# Xamarin.Forms Datepicker in PopUp

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, uwp, datepicker, popup

I create a project with Xamarin.Forms via MVVM, in which I want to generate a popup that accepts two data via a data picker. The user should specify a start date and an end date. Since I already needed it elsewhere, I already downloaded the ACR.UserDialogs NuGet package. I have also set up a DialogService in which the dialog receives three string parameters and would actually like a similar solution for the data picker. Does anyone have any idea how I can go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuget packages: rg.plugins.popup, propertychanged.fody

**MainView.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:datepickerpopup="clr-namespace:DatePickerPopup"
             x:Class="DatePickerPopup.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <datepickerpopup:MainViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Open Popup"
                Command="{Binding OpenPopup_Command}"
                />

        <Label Text="{Binding SetDates_.StartDate}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding SetDates_.EndDate}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DatePickerPopup
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public SetDates SetDates_ { get; set; } = new SetDates();


        public Command OpenPopup_Command => new Command(async () => 
        {
            DatePickerPop pop = new DatePickerPop();
            var vm = pop.BindingContext as DatePickerViewModel;
            vm.Save_Command = PopupSave_Command;
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(pop);
        });

        public Command PopupSave_Command => new Command(async(param) => 
        {
            SetDates_ = param as SetDates;
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
        });

    }
}
```

**DatePickerPop.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<animations:PopupPage  xmlns:animations="http://rotorgames.com"
                       xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                       xmlns:datepickerpopup="clr-namespace:DatePickerPopup"
                       x:Class="DatePickerPopup.DatePickerPop">
    <animations:PopupPage.BindingContext>
        <datepickerpopup:DatePickerViewModel/>
    </animations:PopupPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 BackgroundColor="White">
        <DatePicker Date="{Binding SetDates_.StartDate}"/>
        <DatePicker Date="{Binding SetDates_.EndDate}"/>

        <Button Text="Save"
                Command="{Binding Save_Command}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding SetDates_}"/>
        <Button Text="Cancel"
                Command="{Binding Cancel_Command}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</animations:PopupPage>
```

**DatePickerViewModel.cs**

```
using Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace DatePickerPopup
{
    public class DatePickerViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public SetDates SetDates_ { get; set; } = new SetDates();
        public Command Save_Command { get; set; }
        public Command Cancel_Command => new Command(async () => 
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync());
    }
}
```

**SetDates.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace DatePickerPopup
{
    public class SetDates : BaseViewModel
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```